Distill whether a day is a weekend date
I have the following data.frame:
 dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12)
 df <- data.frame(dates)
 df$week_day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$dates))

I now would like to know whether the dates are actually a weekend day or now.
Therefore I have tried:
 df$weekday <- as.character(df$week_day)


 
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
 if(df$week_day[i] == "Saturday"){
  df$Weekend[i] == 1
  } else if (df$week_day[i] == "Monday"){
  df$Weekend[i] == 1
  }
 }

This however does not work. Any thoughts why this is not working? And what I should do :).

You can do
D = data.frame(dates = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12L))
D$day = weekdays(D$dates, abbreviate = TRUE)
D$weekday = !D$day %in% c("Sat", "Sun")

> D
        dates day weekday
1  1999-06-17 Thu    TRUE
2  1999-08-21 Sat   FALSE
3  1999-05-16 Sun   FALSE
4  1999-02-16 Tue    TRUE
5  1999-02-18 Thu    TRUE
6  1999-09-17 Fri    TRUE
7  1999-09-22 Wed    TRUE
8  1999-12-27 Mon    TRUE
9  1999-11-06 Sat   FALSE
10 1999-04-29 Thu    TRUE
11 1999-04-05 Mon    TRUE
12 1999-08-03 Tue    TRUE


The following should work
df$weekend <- df$week_day %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")

There’s no need for a loop, nor for as.character() (your week_day column is already of type character).
